# CUPS configuration assistance

Tags: debian, cups

I'm working on setting up Debian Wheezy as a print server (among other things) in our company network.

So far I have succeeded at:

- Installing Debian Wheezy
- Configuring SSH
- Getting VNC running
- Getting CUPS running
- Setting up networked printers in CUPS
- Printing test pages on all printers set up in CUPS

Now, I'm running up against my own lack of knowledge of Linux ... well I think I am at least. It may just be unfamiliarity with CUPS.

The thing I am trying to do now is set up a single point or a rule of some sort that allows print jobs to move on down the list of networked printers till there is an open one.

I've been reading over the CUPS documentation (because ya' know RTFM), and while I'm tech savvy, I'm programming raw, so some of this is "English" but not "common English" to me yet. While I mostly understand what the text is saying I'm finding it hard to connect the dots, as it were, between the different commands/options. I'm reasonably sure the answer is staring me in the face but I can't see it.

I don't really want someone to write it for me but a little guidance would be appreciated, even if it's pointing to another part of manual.

Comment: Hey all. I've kept plugging away this and I think I've worked through the bulk of this issue. While I wouldn't have minded a little help I am glad that I seem to have gotten things working. Thanks to those who looked at this. Maybe with my next question I'll get some responses. ;)